# Why token "less" has higher similarity with "more" in Spacy?

Tags: spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I'm trying to find sentences which has the word less or words similar to less. When I tried to find the token similarity with less and all the words in doc. I'm getting words like less, more, which are opposite to each other yet they have higher similarity.

I'm using "en-web-core-lg" pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The similarity function you are using bases its distance metric on context. Even though (or rather because) they are antonyms, `less` and `more` appear in very similar contexts and have similar syntactic relationships with other words, so their embeddings will be very similar. You can replace `more` with `less` in many phrases and they will still make sense (even though the sense will be the opposite). This is called a paradigmatic relation.

More exactly, in this case, they are both adjectives, referring to quantities.

For a concrete example, you might think that `tiny` would be similar to `less`. But consider the following phrase:

"There will be **less** rain tomorrow."

If you replace it with `tiny` you get "There will be **tiny** rain tomorrow" which makes less sense than "There will be **more** rain tomorrow".

Comment: This makes sense but doesn't solve my problem. I want to figure out the context and understand if it's saying something to do more often or less often, telling to consume more or consume less, eat low amounts  or high amounts. when both words are similar how can I code to get the context out of it? Any other approaches are appreciated.